# expected expression before '{' token C

Tags: c, struct

Hello Guys I am getting error (expected expression before '{' token) in vscode but the same code is running fine without error in cxxdroid (android app C/C++)?

help in simple words is highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//along with structure definition
struct Dogs { //Global structure
    int age;
    char name[20];
} labra, bullDog, shiba;

//Seprately
struct Cat { //Global structure
    int age;
    char name[20];
};

struct Cat persian, bombayCat;

int main() {
    persian.age = 2;
    strcpy(persian.name, "Kity");
    printf("Age: %d, Name: %s\n", persian.age, persian.name);
    
    bombayCat = {3, "Blacky"};     //<-- Error
    printf("Age: %d, Name: %s\n", bombayCat.age, bombayCat.name);
    
    labra = {.name = "Jacky", .age = 4}; //Designated Initialization.     //<-- Error
    printf("Age: %d, Name: %s", labra.age, labra.name);
}
```

Comment: It is only called "designated initialization" if you use it in initialization.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign to structs like that: `bombayCat = {3, "Blacky"};`. It's simply not valid syntax since the `{3, "Blacky"}` part is an *initializer list* and can only be used during *initialization*. That is: when a variable is declared and not during *assignment* later on.

- Either you need to initialize the struct at the same time you declare it:

  ```
  struct Cat bombayCat = {3, "Blacky"};
  ```
- Or alternatively you can use assignment through a temporary unnamed struct object, a so-called *compound literal*:

  ```
  bombayCat = (struct Cat){3, "Blacky"};
  ```

Same with your designated initializer example further down.

Comment: but why no error in android c/c++ cxxdroid IDE???

Comment: @SatyamS I have no idea what an "android c/c++ cxxdroid" is. Is it C or C++? It can be both at once. What is the name of the actual compiler? VSCode is not a compiler either but an IDE - when programming you simply must know: 1) which programming language you are using and 2) which compiler you are using. If you don't know, then you can't create programs in any reliable way.

Comment: @SatyamS Are you compiling for C or C++? They are not the same language.

Comment: @Lundin I think I am running gcc compiler

Comment: @Lundin
yes its gcc 
This is command line code runner extension runs.
D:\Practice C progs> cd "d:\Practice C progs\" ; if ($?) { gcc structures.c -o structures } ; if ($?) { .\structures }

Comment: @SatyamS It does not compile in gcc even when using the lax default settings. See for yourself https://godbolt.org/z/WWdn91vvh